# how to perform the following condition in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have created a table using SQL using following condition:

```
create table tbl2 as 
select a.*, rank () over (partition by col1 order by col2) as rnk 
from tbl1
```

now I want to create another table from tbl2 where I want to select the record under following condition: If a record  has only one rank available then I will select that record but if the record has multiple ranks available then I will choose the record with 2nd rank. Let me give an example:

```
col1 rnk
1      1
2      1
2      2
3      1
3      2
3      3
```

Desired output:

```
col1    rnk
1       1
2       2
3       2
```

how do I get my output using SQL?

Comment: what rdbms are you working with?

Comment: I am using oracle 11g

Comment: my answer should work with sql-server, I'm not sure how oracle will handle it. please test it and see. Also, for future questions, please tag the relevant rdbms.

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach would be:

```
select *
from tbl2 t
where rnk = 2 or not exists (select 1 from tbl2 where col1 = t.col1 and rnk <> t.rnk)
```

This won't work for cases where 2nd rank is not 2, though...

Comment: I like this approach more then my own answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT col1, rnk
FROM
(
    SELECT col1, rnk, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY CASE WHEN rnk = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn
    FROM tbl2
) x 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Using [case](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) in the order by of the [row_number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) function gets the `rnk = 2` first and then all others.
Then choose only the records where row_number is 1, so it's either the only record in the `col1` group or the one with `rnk = 2`.